# Not able to start Sonar Server

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

I am using Sonar to generate code review reports of my project. But I am not able to start the server. I am getting

> HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

while running

> StartSonar.bat

file.

Please find the logs generated while sonar start up.

> C:\TEMP2\Sonar\sonarqube-4.5\bin\windows-x86-32>StartSonar.bat wrapper
>   | --> Wrapper Started as Console wrapper  | Launching a JVM... jvm 1
>   | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org jvm 1    |
>   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved. jvm 1 
>   | jvm 1    | 2015.07.28 07:30:51 INFO 
>   app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]:
>   C:\Software\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\java -Xmx256m -Xms256m - Xss256k
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyO nly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\TEMP2\Sonar\sonarqube-4.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org. sonar.search.SearchServer
>   C:\Users\gxs114\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process8934190933893070058properties
>   jvm 1    | 2015.07.28 07:30:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor]
>   Process[search] is up jvm 1    | 2015.07.28 07:30:57 INFO 
>   app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]:
>   C:\Software\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\java -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSi ze=160m
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=fals e -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\TEMP2\Sonar\sonarqube-4.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/* org.sonar.server.app.WebServer
>   C:\Users\gxs114\AppData\Local\Te
>   mp\sq-process4251708419326591677properties jvm 1    | 2015.07.28
>   07:30:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is
>   stopping jvm 1    | 2015.07.28 07:30:58 INFO 
>   app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped wrapper  |
>   <-- Wrapper Stopped
>
> C:\TEMP2\Sonar\sonarqube-4.5\bin\windows-x86-32>

How can I solve this issue ? Any idea/solution appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got the solution from sonar log files itself.  You can find  server start up logs in the sonar.log file under directory "sonarqube-4.5\logs".

I was not able to start the server due to following port binding exception :

```
2015.07.29 02:46:36 ERROR web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:9000
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
```

So, I changed the port number to "4950" from "9000" in sonar.properties file under directory "sonarqube-4.5\conf".

```
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=4950

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1
```

The server got successfully started after changing the port number.

Comment: After changing the port as you suggested:

2016.03.15 16:25:47 ERROR web[o.a.t.u.d.Digester] Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_40-ea]
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_40-ea]

Comment: Sorry, as per your i tried but no change it's throwing same error

Comment: @Gunjan Shah, I am getting like this type error while trying to start sonar
'java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reset file system' . Have you any idea or help ?

Answer (score 8):

If you had already started Sonar and killed the process on command prompt, your JVM would still be running in the background.

Kill the java process and try again, it works. Tried and worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

The reason behind this problem is that port number is already in use by SONAR, you didn't properly end the SONAR.
There are two ways to get rid of this,

1. Identify the port number using log file(sonarqube-4.5\logs). Then identify the PID for that process. Then kill the process using PID.

The log will look like

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: **JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:9000**
```

To find PID

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "port_num"
```

To Kill Process

```
taskkill /F /PID "pid"
```

2. Just log off the system and login again, then start the StartSonar.bat file. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

Task Manager-> Details then Right click-> end task -> for all java.exe  if not sure of port number. Then open again cmd prompt ->startsonar.bat

Answer (score 1):

As per my observation if Eclipse already running then first close the eclipse.
check the port 9000 is free.

then after run the sonar from command prompt once the server is up then after run the eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change the port in **sonar.properties** file

Look **sonar.web.port**="CHANGE_PORT_NUMBER"

Answer (score 0):

I installed sonarqube for swift with Version 0.4.3 is now working ok on SonarQube 7.3 and above : https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift/releases/tag/0.4.3.